# How to know if JFrame was closed by the default exit?

Tags: java, jframe

Is there a way to know if JFrame was closed by pressing X, I mean the default exit button?

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Check out [`WindowListener#windowClosing(WindowEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-)

Comment: Based on my limited expermintation, when closed via the [X], `WindowListener#windowClosing` is invoked, when calling `dispose`, `WindowListener#windowDeactivated` and `WindowListener#windowClosed` are invoked and `WindowListener#windowDeactivated` is invoked when the window is hidden (`setVisible(false)`) ... at least on the Mac